# Sort by with multiple columns that have date values

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to sort two date columns in the table, FinalReviewDate, and DateDelivered.  Any column with a DateDelivered is always going to have a FinalReviewDate that preceeds it, but a project can have a FinalReviewDate without having a DateDelivered. I used ASC to ORDER BY for both columns and received this result.

```
Final Review Date    Date Delivered
NULL                   NULL
NULL                   NULL
xxxx-xx-xx            xxxx-xx-xx
xxxx-xx-xx             NULL


How can I ORDER BY so my result looks like this instead?

Final Review Date    Date Delivered
NULL                   NULL
NULL                   NULL
xxxx-xx-xx             NULL
xxxx-xx-xx             xxxx-xx-xx
```

I don't know how to factor in the NULL values so they're included when I ORDER BY both tables.  Here's the code I'm using.

```
$sql = "SELECT Project, Client, DateReceived, LastName, FinalReviewDate, DateDelivered FROM Projects
              WHERE DateAccepted IS NULL
              ORDER BY FinalReviewDate ASC, DateDelivered ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: This would only work if the 'Final Review Date' of the two bottom rows is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two conditions into begin of `ORDER BY` section: `FinalReviewDate IS NULL DESC, DateDelivered IS NULL DESC`:

```
$sql = "SELECT Project, Client, DateReceived, LastName, FinalReviewDate, DateDelivered 
    FROM Projects
    WHERE DateAccepted IS NULL
    ORDER BY FinalReviewDate IS NULL DESC, DateDelivered IS NULL DESC, 
        FinalReviewDate ASC, DateDelivered ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: That worked beautifully.  So, I take it the first two IS NULL DESC sorted the null values first?

Comment: Yes, `FinalReviewDate IS NULL` return TRUE if field is null. If we want to see these lines at start, we are sorting them in descending order: firsts FALSE, after - TRUE

Comment: I didn't know I could sort those first.  I found several examples on here and tried them, but they didn't work for me.  I appreciate the help.